# How to select table on DB using a dropdown?

Tags: php, postgresql

Let’s say that I have two tables on my DB (table1 and table2, and both of them have the same structure.

```
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 name      | text    |           |          |         | extended |              |
 days_week | text    |           |          |         | extended |              |
 datetime  | tsrange |           |          |         | extended |              |
 room      | text    |           |          |         | extended |              |
 semester  |text     |           |          |         |extended. |              |

Indexes:
“table1_name_days_week_datetime_excel” EXCLUDE USING gist (name with=, days_week with=, date time with &&)
"table1_room_days_week_datetime_excel” EXCLUDE USING gist (room with=, days_week with=, datetime with &&)
```

My goal is to insert the data on the table that I’ll be deleting on the dropdown.

Sample if I select 1° semester on the dropdown all of the data will be added on the table1.

if I select 2° semester on the dropdown all of the data will be added on the table2.

This is what I have so far

```
<form name="testform" method='POST' action="add.php">
<label>Semester</label>
<select type="text" name=semester>
<option value=1ºsemester>1º semester</option>
<option value=2ºsemester>2º semester</option>
</select>
<input type=submit value=Registrar>
</form>

<?php

$semester=$_POST['semester'];

$con = @pg_connect ("port=5432 host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=a");

if($con == NULL) {
echo "Cannot Connect to database.";
exit (0);
}

$sql = "insert into ? (name, days_week, datetime, room, semester) values ('$name', '$days_week', '$datetime', '$room', '$semester');";
$res = @pg_query ($con, $sql);
if ($res == NULL){
echo "Error";

exit (0);
} 
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: _“and both of them have the same structure”_ - then they should probably be just _one_ table in the first place.

Comment: _“Sample if I select 1° semester on the dropdown all of the data will be added on the table1. if I select 2° semester on the dropdown all of the data will be added on the table2.”_ - no. If you select semester 1, then a `1` should be written into the `semester` column of your _one_ table, and if you select semester 2, it should be a `2` instead. Data of the same structure and same meaning, generally belongs into the same table, unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: @04FS if you take close look to the structure of the table you'll see that I'm preventing insertion of overlapping date ranges that's why I came up with this idea of separating the tables. Table1 is to store data (schedule) for the first semester and table2 is for schedule for the second semester. I have not that much knowledge of how to make it simple.

Comment: Multiple tables for the same purpose is a bad design. Rather than dealing with multiple tables why not just add semester to the exclusion.  But that also begs the question wouldn't the date range for each semester be different by definition of semester? Consider a check constraint semester and datetime combination. That still requires only 1 table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a check before executing the query.

```
$semester=$_POST['semester'];
if($semester == '1ºsemester'){
  $table = "table_1";
}else{
  $table = "table_2";
}

$q = "insert into $table ........";
//Rest of your code
```